# $mdToast show/hide causes screen to scroll to top of website when overflow-y is set - AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

I have a simple toast the pops when a user submits a form

```
$mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
    .textContent('Your order form has been submitted.')
    .position('bottom left')
    .hideDelay(5000)
);
```

It works and the toast appears at the bottom left and the user can scroll down the website while it is visible. When it shows/hides it does not scroll the view to the top of the screen. But I was having a bug where the toast was causing the screen to jump because it was hiding the vertical scrollbar and then it was reappearing.

To fix this I added

```
html {
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

This stopped the screen from jumping but now when the toast shows/hides it scrolls the screen to the top of the page.

How can I stop it from scrolling on show/hide?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem,

I fixed it this way:

Add a dedicated div in the body:

```
<div id="toast-container"></div>
```

With this CSS:

```
  #toast-container
    position fixed
    top 0
    right 0
    left 0
    bottom 0
    visibility hidden
    > *
      visibility visible
```

Then, just add the parent in the call:

```
  $mdToast.show({
    // ....
    parent: document.getElementById('toast-container')
  });
```